# Determining Perfect vs. Imperfect Information in Calculating Expected Value

Tags: expected-value, decision-theory

In this scenario, you are presented with an opportunity to engage in a game for a fee of $50. On a table, there are two boxes: a large box and a small box. The large box contains a total of 40 balls, comprising 12 blue balls and 28 red balls. Meanwhile, the small box consists of 20 balls, with 16 being blue and 4 red.

The game proceeds with the assumption that one of the boxes has already been randomly selected, and a ball has been drawn from it. You are permitted to discern the color of the drawn ball but are kept unaware of the box's size. If you opt to participate, the ball is returned to the box before the next draw, and a new ball is randomly selected. If this subsequent draw yields a red ball, you win $200.

Would you consider the information about the color of the first ball to be perfect or imperfect?

**Possible answer:** In this context, the information about the color of the first ball can be described as imperfect. While we have knowledge of the color, the lack of information regarding the box's size introduces an element of uncertainty, making the information incomplete for making an entirely informed decision.